# Serenity BDD with JUnit - reports not formatted

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, serenity-bdd

I have just created a serenity project using junit which runs fine but the reports being generated have no formatting. See below. When I create a serenity project using cucumber the report is formatted as expected. are there any additional steps I need to complete to get the report displayed correctly. All I have done is create the project using maven (mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=serenity). then import it into IntelliJ and ran it

[image: report sample].

My POM file is

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>serenityJUnit</groupId>
<artifactId>serenityJUnitDemo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Serenity project with JUnit and WebDriver</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>1.1.38</serenity.version>
    <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
</properties>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/When*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Story.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: All sorted now. It worked when I commented the following line in the serentity

Comment: # Customise your riequirements hierarchy
#serenity.requirement.types=feature, story

Answer (score 0):

worked when I commented out the following line in the properties file

## Customise your riequirements hierarchy

## serenity.requirement.types=feature, story